# how can I get result axios post in react?

Tags: reactjs

I'm changing fetch to axis for http library. so I changed some codes, and got one error.
the insert request is working well, but the respone at reactjs is error.
how can I solve this?

*mycode*

```
handleFormSubmit=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        this.addCustomer()   //here is the part of the error
        .then((response)=>{
            console.log(response.data);
            this.props.stateRefresh();
        })

        this.state = {
            username:"",
            birthday:"",
            gender:"",
            job:"", 
        }

    }

    addCustomer = async()=>{
        const url = '/api/customers';

        const formData = new FormData();
        //formData.append('image',this.state.file);
        formData.append('name',this.state.username);
        formData.append('birthday',this.state.birthday);
        formData.append('gender',this.state.gender);
        formData.append('job',this.state.job);

        return axios.post(url, formData) 
        .then( response => { })
        .catch( error => { console.log('failed', error) })

    }
```

*error*

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
(anonymous function)
src/components/CustomerAdd.js:37
  34 | e.preventDefault()
  35 | this.addCustomer()
  36 | .then((response)=>{
> 37 |     console.log(response.data);
     | ^  38 |     this.props.stateRefresh();
  39 | })
  40 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are already catching the success case of your Promise in `addCustomer` when doing `.then( response => { })`

Simply remove this line and you should be fine. (Considering that your API is indeed returning something for a POST request)

Answer (score 0):

Your add customer method is not returning a promise and. then wouldn't work on it. Kindly refactor to look like this:

```
addCustomer = () => { 
//other codes
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios
      .post(url, formData)
      .then(response => resolve(response))
      .catch(error => {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
};

this.addCustomer.then(response => console.log(response.data)).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

or

just `return axios.post(url, formData)` 
and you'll be fine since axios already returns a promise

Comment: `axios.post()` already returns a Promise. There's no need to wrap it in a `Promise`.

Comment: Yes, I felt this would be clearer to him... he can also just ```return axios.post(url, formData)```

Answer (score 0):

Your *then()* in the *addCustomer* function is kind of deleting the *response*

```
return axios.post(url, formData)
  .then( response => { }) // returning an empty object instead of the response
  .catch( error => { console.log('failed', error) })
```

try

```
await axios.post(url, formData)
      .catch( error => { console.log('failed', error) })
```

or without the *async*:

```
return axios.post(url, formData)
          .catch( error => { console.log('failed', error) })
```